# Replace a label in check box list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to replace a label with hyperlink using jquery. However it is not working for me. I want each list item to have a specific hyperlink based on their value. 
Here's what I have tried.. 
JQuery code:

```
        $('.chkList li label').each(function () {

            if ($(this).val() == "1")
                $this.replaceWith('<a href="">link 1</a>');
            if($(this).val() == "2")
                $this.replaceWith('<a href="">link 2</a>');
        });
```

asp.net code:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList" runat="server" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" CssClass="chkList">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: 1) `var $this=$(this);` 2) `$this.val()`

Comment: are you a) including the jQuery library in your document and b) wraping your code in $(document).ready(function(){})?

Comment: @gabgrif  yes I am, but I didnt include this in the above code

Comment: if ($(this).val() == 1)

Comment: Updated but it's still not replacing the label with the hyperlink @Rayon

Comment: none of these li's actually have labels - try $('.chkList ul li ').each...also youre referencing a class with te chkList is the id of the list.

Comment: @gavgrif by checking the dom model, its like this <ul id="chkList" class="chkList">
 <li><input id="chkList_0" type="checkbox" name="chkList$0" value="1"><label for="chkList_0">A</label></li></ul> so therefore i have added label

Comment: @KhalifaSabt take a look at my answer, it works!

Answer (score 0):

ok - so two things A)
your use of  $this needs to be altered as in the comments, but also I just realised you are comparing the value. All inputs values are strings untill converted to a number so either convert it using parseInt():

```
 if (parseInt($(this).val())== 1)
```

or keep it as a string

```
 if ($(this).val() == "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
<script>
        $('.chkList li').each(function () {

            var myvalue = $(this).html();
            if ($(myvalue).attr("value") == "1")
                $(this).replaceWith('<a href="">link 1</a>');
            if ($(myvalue).attr("value") == "2")
                $(this).replaceWith('<a href="">link 2</a>');
        });
</script>
```